# java.nio.file.Files.setOwner() not permitted

Tags: java, file-permissions, file-attributes, java.nio.file

I am writing an attendance program in Java for use in class; my goal is to be able to have the students download the class file to their accounts (we'll be working on the same network) and then run them with their usernames and a password that will change daily. My program works fine, but I've run into a bug that I can't seem to overcome.

When it's run for the first time in any given day, attend.java will create a new text file in a specified directory on *my* account and then append the username of whoever ran the program to the file (currently it just appends the first argument of the program to the file, but I hope to modify it so it is more accurate and no one can give a false username), thereby compiling a list of students.

For example, running:

```
>> java attend desadams cheesecake
```

will take the given password "cheesecake" and if it matches the day's password either create a new textfile called "(today's date).txt" and write the username "desadams" to it (if it is being run for the first time that day) or else simply append the username "desadams" to the preexisting "(today's date).txt" file.

I wrote my own createFile() method that utilizes the java.nio.file package to create a file with custom permissions:

```
  public static void createFile(File file) throws IOException{
    Path newFile = file.toPath();

    //create new file and set permissions
    /* For the purposes of this program, the new file (the attendance list) must readable and writable to everbody
     * in order for this program to work properly when run from their user, because this program both reads and modif\
ies.
     */
    Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrw-rw-");
    Files.createFile(newFile);
    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(newFile, perms);

    //set owner
    UserPrincipal owner = newFile.getFileSystem().getUserPrincipalLookupService().lookupPrincipalByName("desadams");
    Files.setOwner(newFile, owner);

    //set group
    GroupPrincipal group = newFile.getFileSystem().getUserPrincipalLookupService().lookupPrincipalByGroupName("studen\
ts");
    Files.getFileAttributeView(newFile, PosixFileAttributeView.class).setGroup(group);
  }
```

I could not create the file and set the permissions at the same time, because the umask of the account would get in the way, so I did it in two steps and it works fine.

Now we get to my problem: I can compile and run this program just fine from my own account, but in anticipation of running it from other accounts, I changed the setOwner() method to use an arbitrary username instead of my own to better simulate the conditions of running the program from a different account. And it failed. Attempting to set the owner to anyone other than the person running the program results in an "operation not permitted" error.

I already knew that the UNIX command **chown** would not work because none of the network accounts have access to the root account, but I didn't expect it to prevent Java from doing the same thing, though I suppose it does make sense.

Is there anyway at all to get around this? The simplest way, of course, would be to run the program myself prior to anyone else each day, so that the attendance file is created in my own username and then I wouldn't have to worry about making sure to set the owner to my username within the program itself; it will always find the attendance file and thus not have to create it with the proper file attributes. However, though that may be exactly what I do, I would like to know if anyone has a solution that suggests how to set the owner within the program itself.

Thanks, and sorry this was a long post.

Answer (score 0):

If the users are sudoers on your system, you could have them do `sudo java attend desadams cheesecake`. However, I expect they are not sudoers, and therefore your solution where you create the file first is probably the best one.